# Implementing onActivityResult() in a Service

Tags: java, android, service, onactivityresult, startactivityforresult

I have the following code, which should record the device screen, using a service.

The problem is that to use it I need to use a call like: `startActivityForResult/onActivityResult`, for the permission thing to be able to record the screen.

But on Android Service there is no such call.

I have to start something like this:

```
startActivityForResult (mProjectionManager.createScreenCaptureIntent (), CAST_PERMISSION_CODE);
```

code:

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode != CAST_PERMISSION_CODE) {
            Log.w("class:", "Unknown request code: " + requestCode);
            return;
        }
        Log.w("class:", "onActivityResult:resultCode");
        if (resultCode != RESULT_OK) {
            startRec = false;
            Toast.makeText(this, "Screen Cast Permission Denied :(", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }
        prepareRecording("start");
        mMediaProjection = mProjectionManager.getMediaProjection(resultCode, data);

        Log.w("class:", "onActivityResult:mMediaProjection");

        // TODO Register a callback that will listen onStop and release & prepare the recorder for next WidgetProvider
        // mMediaProjection.registerCallback(callback, null);
        mVirtualDisplay = getVirtualDisplay();
        mMediaRecorder.start();
    }
```

How can I make any suggestions?

full code:

```
package com.unkinstagram;

import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.hardware.display.DisplayManager;
import android.hardware.display.VirtualDisplay;
import android.media.MediaRecorder;
import android.media.projection.MediaProjection;
import android.media.projection.MediaProjectionManager;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.File;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

import static android.app.Activity.RESULT_OK;

class Constants {
    public interface ACTION {
        public static String MAIN_ACTION = "com.unkinstagram.action.main";
        public static String STARTFOREGROUND_ACTION = "com.unkinstagram.action.startforeground";
        public static String STOPFOREGROUND_ACTION = "com.unkinstagram.action.stopforeground";
        public static String REC_ACTION = "com.unkinstagram.action.rec";
        public static String STOP_ACTION = "com.unkinstagram.action.stop";
    }

    public interface NOTIFICATION_ID {
        public static int FOREGROUND_SERVICE = 101;
    }
}

public class ForegroundService extends Service {
    private static final String LOG_TAG = "class:";

    private static final int CAST_PERMISSION_CODE = 22;
    private DisplayMetrics mDisplayMetrics;
    private MediaProjection mMediaProjection;
    private VirtualDisplay mVirtualDisplay;
    private MediaRecorder mMediaRecorder;
    private MediaProjectionManager mProjectionManager;

    private boolean startRec = false;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        mDisplayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        mMediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
        mProjectionManager = (MediaProjectionManager) getSystemService(Context.MEDIA_PROJECTION_SERVICE);
        WindowManager window = (WindowManager) getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
        window.getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(mDisplayMetrics);
        Log.v(LOG_TAG,"create");
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        if (intent.getAction().equals(Constants.ACTION.STARTFOREGROUND_ACTION)) {
            Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Received Start Foreground Intent ");
            Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity2.class);
            notificationIntent.setAction(Constants.ACTION.MAIN_ACTION);
            notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);

            Intent recIntent = new Intent(this, ForegroundService.class);
            recIntent.setAction(Constants.ACTION.REC_ACTION);
            PendingIntent pRecIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, recIntent, 0);

            Intent stopIntent = new Intent(this, ForegroundService.class);
            stopIntent.setAction(Constants.ACTION.STOP_ACTION);
            PendingIntent pStopIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, stopIntent, 0);

            Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                    .setContentTitle("Stai per registrare lo schermo del device.")
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_videocam_off)
                    .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                    .setOngoing(true)
                    .addAction(0, "Rec", pRecIntent)
                    .addAction(0, "Stop", pStopIntent)
                    .build();
            startForeground(Constants.NOTIFICATION_ID.FOREGROUND_SERVICE, notification);

        } else if (intent.getAction().equals(Constants.ACTION.REC_ACTION)) {
            Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Clicked Rec");
            startRecording();
        } else if (intent.getAction().equals(Constants.ACTION.STOP_ACTION)) {
            Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Clicked Stop");
            stopRecording();
            stopForeground(true);
            stopSelf();
        } else if (intent.getAction().equals(Constants.ACTION.STOPFOREGROUND_ACTION)) {
            Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Received Stop Foreground Intent");
            stopForeground(true);
            stopSelf();
        }
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "In onDestroy");
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    private void startRecording() {
        startRec = true;
        // If mMediaProjection is null that means we didn't get a context, lets ask the user
        Log.w("class:", "startRecording:start");
        if (mMediaProjection == null) {
            // This asks for user permissions to capture the screen
            Log.w("class:", "startRecording:startResult");
            startActivityForResult(mProjectionManager.createScreenCaptureIntent(), CAST_PERMISSION_CODE);
            Log.w("class:", "startRecording:endResult");
            return;
        }
        Log.w("class:", "startRecording:end");
        mVirtualDisplay = getVirtualDisplay();
        mMediaRecorder.start();
    }

    private void stopRecording() {
        startRec = false;
        Log.w("class:", "stopRecording:start");
        if (mMediaRecorder != null) {
            mMediaRecorder.stop();
            mMediaRecorder.reset();
            //mMediaRecorder = null;
        }
        if (mVirtualDisplay != null) {
            mVirtualDisplay.release();
            //mVirtualDisplay = null;
        }
        if (mMediaProjection != null) {
            mMediaProjection.stop();
            //mMediaProjection = null;
        }
        Log.w("class:", "stopRecording:end");
    }

    public String getCurSysDate() {
        return new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd_HH-mm-ss").format(new Date());
    }

    private void prepareRecording(String name) {
        if (!Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(Environment.getExternalStorageState())) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Failed to get External Storage", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }
        final String directory = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "Recordings";
        final File folder = new File(directory);
        boolean success = true;
        if (!folder.exists()) {
            success = folder.mkdir();
        }
        if (!success) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Failed to create Recordings directory", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }

        String videoName = (name + "_" + getCurSysDate() + ".mp4");
        String filePath = directory + File.separator + videoName;

        int width = mDisplayMetrics.widthPixels;
        int height = mDisplayMetrics.heightPixels;

        mMediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
        mMediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.SURFACE);
        mMediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
        mMediaRecorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.H264);
        mMediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
        mMediaRecorder.setVideoEncodingBitRate(8000 * 1000);
        mMediaRecorder.setVideoFrameRate(24);
        mMediaRecorder.setVideoSize(width, height);
        mMediaRecorder.setOutputFile(filePath);

        try {
            mMediaRecorder.prepare();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }

    }

    private VirtualDisplay getVirtualDisplay() {
        int screenDensity = mDisplayMetrics.densityDpi;
        int width = mDisplayMetrics.widthPixels;
        int height = mDisplayMetrics.heightPixels;
        return mMediaProjection.createVirtualDisplay(this.getClass().getSimpleName(),
                width, height, screenDensity,
                DisplayManager.VIRTUAL_DISPLAY_FLAG_AUTO_MIRROR,
                mMediaRecorder.getSurface(), null, null);
    }

    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode != CAST_PERMISSION_CODE) {
            Log.w("class:", "Unknown request code: " + requestCode);
            return;
        }
        Log.w("class:", "onActivityResult:resultCode");
        if (resultCode != RESULT_OK) {
            startRec = false;
            Toast.makeText(this, "Screen Cast Permission Denied :(", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }
        prepareRecording("start");
        mMediaProjection = mProjectionManager.getMediaProjection(resultCode, data);

        Log.w("class:", "onActivityResult:mMediaProjection");

        // TODO Register a callback that will listen onStop and release & prepare the recorder for next WidgetProvider
        // mMediaProjection.registerCallback(callback, null);
        mVirtualDisplay = getVirtualDisplay();
        mMediaRecorder.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: @TimCastelijns: So what do you recommend? it's very important for me.
To better understand what I have to do, start with this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54009658/creating-a-single-instance-through-a-singleton-of-a-main-activity-to-record-the

I had been advised to use the services.

Answer (score 1):

So you want to use MediaProjection in a Service. To use MediaProjection, you need user to grant permission and then use the Intent returned in the onActivityResult to create a MediaProjection. However, you're in a service and no onActivityResult is available.

Here is an useful github issue: https://github.com/mtsahakis/MediaProjectionDemo/issues/7. There're also some gists you can use.

The basic idea is using an Activity to ask for permission and then start your service with an Intent wrapping the result Intent(Intent is also a parceable so it can be put into another Intent).

Comment: I'm not sure I understood it completely well.
From what I understand it is very complex as a thing.
The problem starts from here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54009658/creating-a-single-instance-through-a-singleton-of-a-main-activity-to-record-the
Where I had been advised to use the services.

Answer (score 1):

While a service can be involved in the screen recording, asking permission has to be done from an activity. So, ask for permission before you start your service.

For example, in [this sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/v8.13/MediaProjection/andcorder), while [the `RecorderService`](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/blob/v8.13/MediaProjection/andcorder/app/src/main/java/com/commonsware/android/andcorder/RecorderService.java) is what actually starts and stops the screen recording, [the `MainActivity`](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/blob/v8.13/MediaProjection/andcorder/app/src/main/java/com/commonsware/android/andcorder/MainActivity.java) is what requests permission, before starting that service. That activity uses `Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar`, so it has no UI of its own, other than the system permission dialog.

Comment: It seems to be just what I'm looking for, for the moment I just gave a quick look.
My doubts / and advice are these:
1) Advice, why do not you use such a thing to save the file name:
public String getCurSysDate () {
        return new SimpleDateFormat ("yyyy-MM-dd_HH-mm-ss"). format (new Date ());
    }
2) External audio is not recorded, right?
3) In your opinion, how can I put the time that passes from the beginning of the recording into the setContentTitle, for example 0 sec, 10 sec, 1min and 30 sec.

Comment: @Paul: "why do not you use such a thing to save the file name" -- because this book example is complex enough as it is. "External audio is not recorded, right?" -- correct. In theory, you could record that through `MediaRecorder` and attempt to use something like `MediaMuxer` to merge them. I have not tried that. "how can I put the time that passes from the beginning of the recording into the setContentTitle" -- if you mean for the `Notification`, you should be able to just update the `Notification` using `NotificationManager` and the ID that you used with `startForeground()`.

Comment: In reality the fact of the audio is very simple just do so:
recorder = new MediaRecorder ();
recorder.setAudioSource (MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC); recorder.setVideoSource (MediaRecorder.VideoSource.SURFACE);
  recorder.setOutputFormat (MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
recorder.setVideoFrameRate (config.frameRate);
recorder.setVideoEncoder (MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.H264);
recorder.setAudioEncoder (MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
recorder.setVideoSize (config.width, config.height);
recorder.setVideoEncodingBitRate (config.bitRate);
....

Comment: Add permissions:
  <uses-permission android: name = "android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
The thing that I'm not really sure is how to request runtime permissions for versions> 7.0.
I think the request should go in the activity, what do you think?

Comment: For the fact of the notification I'm not sure on which way is the right one, consider that I have to update the title of the notification every second.

Comment: P.Š.
I took a look at the link you indicated to me,
I saw the projects.
If the documentation were written a few lines more, accompanied with an image to better understand what it does, it would be much better, you know if an outsider sees the project, takes a long time to understand what it does and if it is right for you.
;)

Comment: @Paul: The documentation for the project is in the form of [this book](https://commonsware.com/Android). "I think the request should go in the activity" -- you have no choice, for the same reason that you needed the activity for the media projection token.